# Cannot resolve git conflicts

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I'm trying to resolve git conflicts but without success. I get this:

```
git checkout PRM-1549-backend-functionality.  // this the feature branch 
git pull origin staging               // this is target branch 

> % git pull origin staging
From bitbucket.org:company/nodeserver
 * branch            staging    -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging server/server.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in server/server.js
error: could not apply 8f72a5b... Revert "add missed twap code"
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 8f72a5b... Revert "add missed code"
> % 

// here I manually merge the changes into IntelliJ

> % git add server/server.js                                   
> % git rebase --continue
```

// Here text file is opened. I save it using the command :wq!

```
> % git branch
* (no branch, rebasing PRM-1549-backend-functionality)
  PRM-1549-backend-functionality
  master
> nodeserver %
```

I don't understand why I'm still in `* (no branch, rebasing PRM-1549-backend-functionality)` Do you know what are the proper steps to fix the conflict so I can merge the changes into `staging` branch?

Comment: Do I interpret this correctly that there is no output of `git rebase --continue`?

Comment: When I type it I'm redirected to text file. I save it and that's it.

Comment: What does `git status` say ? Perhaps you have more conflicts when the next commit is replayed.